# How to find the folder for changing the theme of IDLE on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I'm on Mac, and I downloaded Python 3.8 from its original website. I wanted to have a custom theme for IDLE and a simple google search gave me this [theme from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/jaimergp/10285906). The instructions written on that page are

- Place this  file inside your ~/.idlerc/ folder
- or paste its contents inside
- /path/to/python/idlelib/config-highlight.def
- Adapted from SublimeText's Monokai

but I couldn't find .idlerc folder, the only things that are in Python 3.8 folder are [image]

and I even tried looking for the [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG9GedugQ1A) but there are not TexEdit file where I can paste that theme from GitHub. Can someone guide me step by step about how to add that custom theme?

Comment: `~` is your home directory. From your terminal you can get there by typing `cd ~`

Comment: @PaulH I opened cd ~/idle.rc and then opened nano and pasted that script. What to do next?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with IDLE, but I imagine that you'll want to save and close that file, and then restart IDLE

Comment: After restarting, select Options -> Keys tab.  The select Custom theme Monokai.  (Step 5 in Knight's answer.)  The referenced theme is a dark theme.  IDLE now comes with a built-in dark theme, but surely different from Monokai.  This question and the answer suggest that it would be nice to have an option on the Highlights and Keys tabs to install themes and keysets from files.  I will think about it when we revise those tabs.

Answer (score 1):

All right, even using TinkerTool and clicking on "Show system and hidden files" doesn't enable us to locate .idlerc file in Finder. Follow this procedure to change the theme of IDLE with a custom theme on Mac

1. Open terminal and type the command `cd ~` then `ls -al`
2. You can see .idlrc file among the large number of outputs, to open the .idlerc folder type the command `cd ~/.idlerc`, the folder will open. In order to know what the folder contains type the command `ls -al`.
3. In the output you can see **config-main.cfg** and **config-highlight.cfg**, we have to edit these two files. Type the command `open -a TextEdit config-main.cfg`, a TextEdit window will open up and in that type

`[Theme]`

`default = 0`

`name = monokai`

Press Command + S to save the changes.

4. Type the command `open -a TextEdit config-highlight.cfg` and a TextEdit window will open up. In that window paste the whole code of the theme (from that GitHub page) and save the changes.
5. Open the IDLE -> IDLE (on the top bar) -> Preferences -> Highlights-> Custom Theme.

## All the credit goes to [John Rennie Sir.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1325/john-rennie)

Comment: Step 5 duplicates step 3.  Using the config dialog to select the installed custom theme should be easier and is definitely safer.  If one wants to switch back and forth, it is definitely easier.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes, editing config-main.cfg changes the theme by itself.

Comment: I recommend editing though the dialog because mis-editing the file disables it.

Comment: There is a built-in IDLE Dark under  IDLE -> IDLE (on the top bar) -> Preferences -> Highlights -> a Built-in Theme -> IDLE Dark